# MySQL query not giving me the avrage, sating unknow column

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me by taking a look at the query and tell me what im doing wrong?

Code:

```
select 
bc.bydesign_id as bydesign_client_id, 
bc.first_name, 
bc.last_name, 
bc.email, sum(bo.total_price) as total_amount, 
sum(bo.total_price - bo.total_tax - bo.total_shipping) as subtotal_amount, 
sum(bo.total_price * count(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT count(*)) as avg_amount,
count(*) as order_count
from bydesign_customer bc, bydesign_order bo
where bo.created_at > {d '2020-01-01'}
and bo.created_at < {d '2020-12-31'}
and bo.bydesign_customer_id = bc.bydesign_id
group by bc.bydesign_id
order by subtotal_amount desc
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
```

if i comment out this line below the query runs fine

```
sum(bo.total_price * count(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT count(*)) as avg_amount,
```

Comment: You cannot use and aggregate function within an aggregate function..

Comment: Thank you for your response, how would i rewrite it them to get the result im looking for?

Comment: To be honest I cannot figure out what you are trying to do. And what's wrong with the built in AVG function? Sample data and expected outcome would help.(as text)

Comment: the only line im having problems with is this one

sum(bo.total_price * count(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT count(*)) as avg_amount,

im trying to get the average dollar amount for each client

Comment: And what's wrong with the AVG function?

Comment: @P.Salmon its giving me this error "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function" if i comment it out the query works but i need the avg

Comment: An average is a total divided by number of occurences which is what AVG does - why are you trying something different and COUNT(DISTINCT count(*) is nonsense even if it did work it would always return 1. You really need to add sample data as text to the question together with desired outcome - you only need it from 1 table (that which contains) tables and only a representative sample. See my answer for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear why you are attempting to reinvent the wheel

```
create table t(client_id int, total_price int);

insert into t values 
(1,10),(1,20),(2,10);
select sum(total_price) sumtotal,count(*) cnt,sum(total_price)/count(*) avglonghand,
         avg(total_price) avgfuntion,
         (sum(total_price) * count(*))  sumtotalcount
from t
group by client_id;

+----------+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+
| sumtotal | cnt | avglonghand | avgfuntion | sumtotalcount |
+----------+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+
|       30 |   2 |     15.0000 |    15.0000 |            60 |
|       10 |   1 |     10.0000 |    10.0000 |            10 |
+----------+-----+-------------+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Note the last column - given this outcome what values would you substitute in the calculation

sum(bo.total_price * count(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT count(*)) ??

Comment: Thank you! i have not written SQL in a while so im rusty but you example above helped me out. i needed to change.

sum(bo.total_price * count(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT count(*)) as avg_amount,

to

bo.total_price * count(*) / count(*) as avg_rder_amount,